# Getting Cocoapods Session Verification Error While Updating Version of Pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec, gemspecs

[image]I am unable to push my pod's version. I am continuously getting an error while session verification. Please check and help with it.

We are trying to update our pod's version on it. It should verify my account successfully as always.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this. The user is verified successfully but the message page is showing an error. I tried to publish the pod that was successfully published.